# How to make duplicate values unique?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have records with duplicate values in a column.

For example:

```
INVOICENUM  PRODUCT
-------------------
  789789    ABROPT
  789789    ABROPT
  719648    AZGTEL
  754114    GRTYPT
```

I have 2 records with duplicate invoice numbers, for the first number I want to add 'a' for the second I want to add 'b' and so on.

```
INVOICENUM  PRODUCT
-------------------
 789789a    ABROPT
 789789b    ABROPT
 719648     AZGTEL
 754114     GRTYPT
```

How can I fix this with SQL - I'm using SQL Server 2012 and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.3000.0?

Comment: Did you try any query?

Comment: Is there a possibility for third duplicate?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.3000.0

Comment: Do you have any id column which you didn't specified?

Comment: There is no id column, the goal is to make INVOICENUM the id column

Comment: If that's the goal, you should reconsider. Why do you you want to have duplicate values in the first place?

Comment: @Kuzgun it's even possible to have more then three duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok well assuming SQL Server (with rownumber feature) then this seems to work

```
select
    INVOICENUM = case 
        when INVOICENUM in (select INVOICENUM from YourTable group by INVOICENUM having COUNT(*) > 1)
        then INVOICENUM + char(96+row_number() over (partition by INVOICENUM order by INVOICENUM))
        else INVOICENUM 
    end,
    PRODUCT,
    OtherColumn,
    AnotherColumn
from 
    YourTable
```

Although its not particularly elegant...

The idea here is to get a row number to seed the int-to-character function [`CHAR(...)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx). Where 96 is the ASCII code for the character before **a** - so rownumber of 1 gives **a** (ie Ascii code of 97), row number of 2 gives **b** (ie Ascii code of 98) and so on...
I've thrown the case statement in there to exclude scenarios when there are no duplicates and so it just gives back the InvoiceNum without adding a letter...

Heres my test example...

```
declare @data table (INVOICENUM nvarchar(100), PRODUCT nvarchar(100))

insert into @data
values ('789789', 'ABROPT')
,('789789', 'ABROPT')
,('719648', 'AZGTEL')
,('754114', 'GRTYPT')

select
    INVOICENUM = case 
        when INVOICENUM in (select INVOICENUM from @data group by INVOICENUM having COUNT(*) > 1)
        then INVOICENUM + char(96+row_number() over (partition by INVOICENUM order by INVOICENUM))
        else INVOICENUM 
    end,
    PRODUCT
from 
    @data
```

Comment: My table contains thousands of records and more then 20 columns, I just mentioned 2 columns and 4 records :p

Comment: @jitsCode not sure what your point is? `@data` is there to help test the problem in your case you'd replace @data with your table name and you'd add the columns you want to the select...

Comment: do I have to write down all records in the insert statement? Or is there another way to do this.

Comment: @jitsCode please don't take this the wrong way but I've made the assumption that you know some sql and that you can take my solution and apply it to your particular database schema (ie your tables and columns). Ignore the test example ie the code declaring and populating `@data` and focus on the first code block where I've put `from YourTable`.

Comment: @jitsCode Whats the name of the table that holds your invoice records?

Comment: Your solution works but the problem with this is when reaching 'z' I get symbols added behind my invoice number eg. '789789‡', '789789‰', '789789…' .

Comment: @jitsCode yep that's a problem - but without stating what should happen when you have more than 26 duplicates, we're not going to be able to mindread what should happen :)

Comment: @jitsCode I recommend you look at the answer by *Dmitry Bychenko* - its the same idea but the case codition is done in a different way - it should work faster.

Answer (score 2):

Often such problems are solved via *Analytic functions*.

```
select case
         when (count(1) over(partition by InvoiceNum) > 1) then
           InvoiceNum + Char(row_Number() over(partition by InvoiceNum order by InvoiceNum) + 96)
         else
           InvoiceNum
       end as InvoiceNum,
       Product    
  from MyTable
```

The main *advantage* of Analytic functions is the *performance*.

Comment: The op confirmed *SQL Server 2012* in the question comments.

Comment: This is pretty much the same as approach as my answer (use ascii code to seed the character based on rownumber)

Comment: Note: you've used 64 to start the characters (which will give uppercase letters) @jitsCode has used lowercase letters in the example...

Comment: @Chris Moutray: Thank you! I've missed the issue. I've updated the 64 to required 96 in the code.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I see how this is working now (but I'm using sql 2008) I can get this to work if i remove the `order by` from the case condition and if i change `||` to `+`. Also not sure theres a need for the convert to varchar if the column is already a varchar.

Comment: PS execution plan does show this method giving better performance :)

Comment: @Chris Moutray: You're quite right: it's better to remove "order by" from the case condition, though MS SQL 2012 tolerates it. Usually (esp. on large tables) analytic functions show much better performance, but, of course it depends on sql.